# Use rust cargo to run tests in workspace root

Tags: rust, integration-testing, rust-cargo

I've got the following rust project layout:

```
project_name
 ├── crate_1
 │     ├── src
 │     │     ...
 │     │     └── main.rs
 │     └── Cargo.toml
 ├── crate_2
 │     ├── src
 │     │     ...
 │     │     └── lib.rs
 │     └── Cargo.toml
 ├── tests
 │     └── tests.rs <-- run tests in here
 └── Cargo.toml
```

I want to run the tests in the `tests` directory using cargo, however cargo can't seem to find them.
Is there a way to get cargo to run them?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/7467

Comment: @Sprite not seeing anywhere in that issue where they mention how to run tests at the workspace level. Can cargo not run tests outside of crates?

Comment: What are the contents of `project_name/Cargo.toml`?

Comment: @eggyal `[workspace]` and `members = [ "crate_1", "crate_2" ]`

Comment: how cna i Run tests for  `bins/src` setup guuis?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[tokio](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio) is a very good example.

Now you already have a `tests` directory, let's add it to the `members` in workspace `Cargo.toml`.

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "crate1",
    "crate2",

    "tests"
]
```

We assume that there are two integration test files, `test_crate1.rs` and `test_crate2.rs` under the `tests` directory.

Create a `Cargo.toml` under the `tests` directory with these contents:

```
[package]
name = "tests"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
publish = false

[dev-dependencies]
crate1 = { path = "../crate1" }
crate2 = { path = "../crate2" }

[[test]]
name = "test_crate1"
path = "test_crate1.rs"

[[test]]
name = "test_crate2"
path = "test_crate2.rs"
```

Run `cargo test` in workspace directory to check it.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a single distributable package, comprised of several workspace crates, and you want to run integration tests from a root `tests` directory.

You don't need to specify the tests directory as a workspace member.

Have a look at how [`clap` does it](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/master/Cargo.toml)

If you tell Cargo that your root `Cargo.toml` is infact a package itself, it will treat the root `tests` directory as normal

```
[package]
name = "your package"
version = "0.0.0"
```